# How are attributive suffixes like "-ean" in "Shakespearean" created?

Tags: suffixes, derivational-morphology

Words like: Orwellian, Socratic, Shakespearean, Marxist, elephantine are all adjectives that mean "relating to or characteristic of *root noun*", but the derivational suffixes applied to the root seem to be very variable.

Where do these suffixes come from? How are they appropriately applied to new words?

Comment: Are you looking for a rule? I don't think there is one. Whoever coins the term gets to decide which suffix to use.

Comment: It could just as easily have been "Orwellic", it's just an accident of history.

Comment: Are they Delawareans or Delawarites?

Comment: A _Marxist_ is a follower of Marx's political views. There is also a word [Marxian](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Marxian) for describing ideas relating to him (_Marxian economics_).

Comment: -ian/-ean seems more common for authors (Shavian, Shakespearean, Joycean, Orwellian) but there are exceptions: Kafkaesque, and Hardyesque seem more common than Hardyan, and some writers seem not to have attracted an adjective (Kingian is used of Martin Luther but not much for Stephen). As others have said, there isn't a general rule, although I'm sure there are patterns you could deduce - not only in the form of the name but the genre of literature.

Answer (score 2):

The suffixes have different derivations which depend on the origin of the words, the historical period etc:, for instance;

***[-ean](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ean#etymonline_v_32104)***:

> variant of -an after names ending in -ea, -es, -eus.
>
> ***-an***;
> word-forming element meaning "pertaining to," from Latin -anus, adjective suffix, in some cases via French -ain, -en. From PIE *-no-.

***-[ic](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ic#etymonline_v_32037)***:

> Middle English -ik, -ick, word-forming element making adjectives, "having to do with, having the nature of, being, made of, caused by, similar to," from French -ique and directly from Latin -icus or from cognate Greek -ikos "in the manner of; pertaining to."

***[-ist](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ist#etymonline_v_12278)***:

> word-forming element meaning "one who does or makes," also used to indicate adherence to a certain doctrine or custom, from French -iste and directly from Latin -ista (source also of Spanish, Portuguese, Italian -ista), from Greek agent-noun ending -istes, which is from -is-, ending of the stem of verbs in -izein, + agential suffix -tes.

(Etymonline)

Recent usage is for example:

> *Trumpists and Trumpian* are terms used to refer to those exhibiting characteristics of Trumpism, whereas political supporters of Trump are known as Trumpers.

(Wikipedia)